# How do I index into a color lookup table (LUT)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

From Photoshop, I exported a 3D LUT as a file with the .cube extension. In the export dialog, I chose grid points=8. The resulting .cube file has 512 data points. To index into the LUT for a given (r,g,b) value, I hash each of r,g, and b into [1,8] then multiply the three resulting values:

`index = rHash * gHash * bHash`

This gives a value between 1 and 512,whch I use to index into the LUT. However, I don't think this is the correct way to calculate the index because it does not give sensible results.

FYI, I'm doing this outside Photoshop, so it's not a question about scripting (just math).

Comment: If this is about maths, then it's not about graphic design and likely off-topic  Perhaps Computer Graphics SE would be better.

Comment: read the specification the order is r+N\*g+N\*N\*b

Comment: joojaa has given the answer I was looking for.